# Sending eth while testing a smart contract

Tags: ether, ethers.js, hardhat, testing, waffle

```js
const sendEth = ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.1")
describe("fund", async function () {
   it("update the amount funded data structure", async function () {
      const options = { value: sendEth }
      await fundMe.fund(options)
      const response = await fundMe.addressToAmount(deployer)
      await assert.equal(response.toString(), sendEth.toString())
    })
 })
```

Error message

```
1) FundMe
       fund
         update the amount funded data structure:
     Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
      at Logger.makeError (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
      at Logger.throwError (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
      at Logger.throwArgumentError (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:285:21)
      at C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-fundme\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:123:16
      at step (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:29:53)
      at fulfilled (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:20:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
```

Can someone help me out with this? I'm running in this error.

Comment: Its complicated to know where is the issue since you're actually doing more than 1 transaction in your test; I suggest that you make no more than 1 transaction per test.. that way you can narrow down your issue

Comment: if you can add more code it would be helpful to find out the issue (a feeling says the deployer is undefined here)